# ExtJS - tagfield default value not firing event

Tags: extjs, extjs6.5.1

I have an ExtJS 6.5.1 app with a tagfield which has a default value using the `value` config. But when the value is set no events (change,select,validitychange etc) are fired.

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2j38) is the fiddle

Should I instead remove the value config and listen for the store to load and then call `setValue()` to trigger the change event?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should call `afterrender: function () {
                this.setValue(0);
            }` and remove `value` config.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is working as expected , alert is fired when on change event occurs  .